# iFrame to Parent LWC postMessage in Community

Tags: lightning-web-components, iframe, postmessage

I have looked through the various posts about this subject, and yet can't get this simple POC to work.

Scenario: Simple Community with LWC. An LWC has an VF page rendered in it as an iFrame. I just want the iFrame to be able to post a message to the parent LWC, in this example using the button on the VF Page. But when I click the button, I don't see anything in the console, and I cannot figure out why? I have tried different version of postMessage, but to no avail?

VF Page:

```xml
 <apex:page id="messagePOC">
     <script>
         function postiframemessage() {
             window.postMessage({name: 'all Done', payload :'fired 1'}, '*');
             window.parent.postMessage({name: 'all Done', payload :'fired 2'}, '*');
         }
         </script>
     <button class="button" onclick="postiframemessage();">Close</button>
 </apex:page>
```

Parent LWC:

```js
 import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';
 
 export default class MessageTest extends LightningElement {
     siteURL;
     connectedCallback() {
         this.siteURL = '/apex/messagePOC';
         window.addEventListener("message", this.handleMessage);
     }
 
     handleMessage = (message) => {
         console.log( 'handlermessage' +  JSON.stringify ( message ) );
         if (message.origin === this.vfOrigin.data) {
             this.receivedMessage = message.data;
             window.console.log(' this.receivedMessage ', this.receivedMessage );
         }
     }
 
 }
```

HTML:

```html
 <template>
 
     <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium slds-modal__content_headless" id="modal-content-id-1">
         <iframe src={siteURL} height="250px" width="450px"></iframe>
     </div>
 
 </template>
```

Comment: There is nothing simple about doing this. We tried hard to do it, tried following a sample provided by a Salesforce tech evangelist and failed mainly because there is no mechanism in Lightning to get a VF URL and in VF to get a Lightning URL. I don't think this is even fixed by the unified URLs update. We gave up and solved differently. Another word of warning, you will have to carefully manage all listeners you add to window in your LWC because the LWC instances are re-used across pages.

Comment: Good to know. Because it is in a Community, all the other options seem to be off the table such as LMS/empAPI etc. - but I think I have to use a VF page for the content I need to display for various reasons, and just need a way for the VF page to say - ok, I am done, you can close me now, which feels like it shouldn't be this hard?!

Comment: LMS should be able to do it now in Experience cloud https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_lms_ga.htm&type=5&release=234

Comment: This page has a big note saying it doesn't work with VF Pages in Experience Builder Sites though, which is the use case here? Or I am mis-reading that note?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/message_channel_considerations.htm

Comment: Because yes, LMS did work in a regular Lighting Page in a non Community scenario

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC Hi what is the approach you went to get the value from VF to LWC using iframe

Comment: I think I embedded the iframe as a child of the LWC, and then passed the params to iFrame as URL params in the src statment